# Creating a Mutable Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a mutable dictionary which I can pass it to another controller so that both the dictionaries in different controllers points to the same memory location. If I change the value at another controller, it is also reflected in the previous controller.
This trick used to work fine with NSMutableDictionary without using any delegates.

My dictionary is of type: [String:AnyObject]

Answer (score 2):

Swift collections are value types, not reference types and although you can pass value types by reference, that lasts only for the lifetime of the call.

What you're doing would be considered bad design — objects are sovereign, with well-defined interfaces, and encapsulated state; they do not informally pool state.

What you probably need to do is take your shared state, formalise an interface to it, and move it to your model. Each controller can separately talk to your model.

Comment: Is it better to make a model or use a delegate for it?

Comment: I would go for a class with static vars that you can access from every controller.

Comment: @Thomas The info is shared among 2 classes only.

Comment: That's fine, the number of classes that access it don't really matter. You could go for adding a static var (with the dictionary) to one of the classes (which would make it accessible from the other class), but a separate class that acts as a data model might be cleaner.

Comment: Taking advantage of reference semantics is not intrinsically bad design, particularly in the user interface layer which is very state dependent.  It is appropriate to use reference semantics, and therefore shared mutable state, in some circumstances.  You do not have enough information about what use this dictionary is being put to to dismiss the design out of hand as "bad".

Comment: I would argue that it is bad design for instances of two separate classes to share instance storage — coupling in any form is a design flaw and the likely outcome, over however much time, is that neither class will be comprehensible without a prior knowledge of the other. Having a third party hold the shared state gives a sole point of responsibility for its coherence and therefore a sole point of maintenance. (... though I am aware that one may need or choose to optimise for outcomes other than design)

Answer (score 0):

Swift's dictionary types are value types whereas your old NSMutableDictionary instances are reference types.

There is nothing that says you HAVE to use Swift's value types in the place of your old dictionary.  If you have a good reason for using reference semantics with the dictionary, go ahead and leave it as an NSMutableDictionary and use the methods of that class to manipulate it.  Just note in your code that you are using NSMutableDictionary explicitly **because** you want the reference semantics.